Can I run q2r.x in Gamma point only?
I wanted to try to calculate force constant using q2r.x (for GaAs). To do that I ran pw.x and then ph.x. These packages ran successfully. But when I ran q2r.x, this job is not finished (23 hr, still running on 2 nodes, 12 cpus). I was wondering and opened q2r.out file and in the header it shows that "GaAs.dyn0 not found". Here are my ph.in and q2r.in files.
ph.in file (considering Gamma point only)
phonon calc.
&INPUTPH
outdir = './'
prefix = 'GaAs'
tr2_ph = 1d-14
epsil = .true.
fildyn = 'GaAs.dyn'
/
0 0 0

q2r.in file
&INPUT
fildyn = 'GaAs.dyn'
zasr = 'crystal'
flfrc = 'GaAs.fc'
/

Actually to run ShengBTE, I need to prepare 2nd order force constant and 3rd order force constant files. And I am only interested in Gamma point. Would you please let me know why it is showing the message?

Are you sure that ph.x ran successfully? q2r.x complains that it cannot find the force constant matrix files (GaAs.dyn0). Can you see GaAs.dyn0, GaAs.dyn1, etc. files in your working directory? It's either your previous steps (ph.x) didn't produce any .dyn files, or you are running q2r.x from some other directory where it doesn't have access to those files.

@AbdulMuhaymin-FreePalestine as I have selected (0 0 0) in ph.in file, after running ph.x, I have seen GaAs.dyn file only (not GaAs.dyn0, GaAs.dyn1 etc). And in my ph.out file, job done is shown.
